# Cocoa Touch- After I removeFromSuperview, how do I bring it back?

Tags: cocoa-touch

For example:

```
- (IBAction)goBtn:(id)sender {
    [urlTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [self loadUrl];
    [goBtn removeFromSuperview];
```

Now `goBtn` is hidden.

How do I, now, bring it back into view?

Comment: Do not repost your questions. If needed, update your original question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. If goBtn's superview was self.view,

```
[self.view addSubview:goBtn]
```

this code will bring ur goBtn back to view